# Typeorm: Execute raw query with parameters

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to execute raw query in **typeorm** with parameters
I tried following queries:

```
insert into data(id, name, gender) values(?, ?,?)
insert into data(id, name, gender) values($1, $2, $3)
insert into data(id, name, gender) values(:id, :name, :gender)
```

The typeorm code is:

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';
await getManager().query(query, [1, 'test', 'male']);
```

What is wrong? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue solved with this link. It depends on the underlying database which syntax to use.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/881

Comment: for some reason $1 doesn't seem to work on postgres when called with something like: query(`SET search_path to $1`, ['tenant']), but works with something like:
query(`call storedProc($1)`, ['param'])

Answer (score 3):

as @ashutosh said, it depends on the driver of your database

For mysql/mysql2 you should use `?` as placehoder. For example

```
manager.query('SELECT id FROM foos WHERE createdAt > ? AND id > ?', [new Date(), 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

For oracle, you can use something like this for me like this :

const querySingleValue = `SELECT *  FROM TABLE1 WHERE name in (:param)`  ;

string value  :

getManager().query(querySingleValue,[param]) ;